# Adobe LiveCycle Designer Convert IFD to XDP Preamble Conversion

Tags: pdf, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am trying to convert an IFD to an XDP in Adobe LiveCycle ES4 Version 11.0.0.2013030303.1.892433. Some forms I have were converted with no problem when opened in LCD. However, other forms will generate the following error in the logs:

```
Msg#:101   Preamble Warning: Not all custom preamble information has been converted. 7 entries have been dropped (*).

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^comment ************************************************************************************

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^comment * NOTE. Because the custom properties JFPREAMBLE_n

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^comment *             will be overwritten when you compile you should

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^comment *             apply your preamble overrides to the JFPREAMBLE

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^comment *             custom property following the reference to the

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^comment *             ^FILE DOCVAR:JFPREAMBLE_1 DICTIONARY  below.

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^comment ************************************************************************************

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^FILE DOCVAR:JFPREAMBLE_1 DICTIONARY

Msg#:101   Preamble -     ^comment *    Preamble overrides...

Msg#:101   Preamble * ^define group:D_NVRA_PAGE_1!OnBOF   @group:SWITCHPAGE.\field$POSITION.  

Msg#:101   Preamble * ^define group:D_NVRA_PAGE_2!OnBOF   @group:SWITCHPAGE.\field$POSITION.  

Msg#:101   Preamble * ^define group:D_NVRA_PAGE_3!OnBOF   @group:SWITCHPAGE.\field$POSITION.  

Msg#:101   Preamble * ^define group:D_NVRA_PAGE_4!OnBOF   @group:SWITCHPAGE.\field$POSITION.  

Msg#:101   Preamble * ^define group:D_NVRA_PAGE_5!OnBOF   @group:SWITCHPAGE.\field$POSITION.  

Msg#:101   Preamble * ^define group:D_NVRA_PAGE_6!OnBOF   @group:SWITCHPAGE.\field$POSITION.

Msg#:101   Preamble * ^define group:JFEndData!EndData        @(If(@(Mod (@$Page.,2))==1,"@group:SWITCHPAGE.","")).

Msg#:101   Preamble Conversion from IFD to XDP is complete.
```

When I go to "preview PDF," the form only shows one blank page. I am very new to PDFs and LC in general, so I do not know where to begin in solving this problem. I apologize if this is a duplicate post. Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated!

*Edit: Grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, LiveCycle Designer can't convert custom preambles but can convert standard preambles that are generated from Output Designer.  The text of the message you provided looks like the standard preamble has been augmented with some additional custom commands.

The warning is indicating that that some of the custom preamble commands will need to be converted manually to equivalent LiveCycle code.

There is the [Central Migration Guide](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/livecycle/pdfs/lces-central-migration.pdf) to assist with this task however it does assume a certain level of both Output Designer and LiveCycle Designer knowledge.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thank you for the explanation! Is there a way to remove or modify the custom preambles?

Comment: Yes.  You can do that using Output Designer although I don't think you need to.  If LiveCycle Designer can't convert them it doesn't really do anything (except maybe include them as comments which you can delete if you want to get rid of them).